# Linear regression with shift function in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, shift

I have two variables, Production (y) and Rigs (x). Drilling Rigs causes production, but Rigs also lead production with 20 time periods (there is a lag time of 20 periods from the start of the drilling rig to production)

**Code**:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smapi

m1 = smapi.OLS.from_formula('Production ~ Rigs.shift(20)', df).fit()

df['Forecast'] = m1.fittedvalues
```

My problem is:

When I run the regression above, I get no forecasted values into the future. Since I have the rig count today, I should be able to predict production 20 periods into the future. What code should I use in Python/Pandas to make this possible?

Best regards

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: https://github.com/Trendofearnings/Git/blob/master/stackoverflow.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

According to what I see on this scatterplot of the data, there is something happening that appears to be missing from the analysis. Starting at the lower left-hand corner, there is a steady and easily-modeled increase up to approximately Rigs=1600 at which point the data abruptly shifts to the left and then again repeats the "steady increase" pattern. This abrupt shift is very large and might have a single cause.
[image: scatterplot]

Comment: Thank you for your input James!  What's missing is rig productivity and a time dummy but I excluded alot of data as it's not relevant for the question. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can shift rigs forward by 20 steps and get a forecast into the future by 20 steps.